# chrome app add local script and script from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, manifest, google-chrome-app

I'm starting a chrome app. But things like this doesn't work for security reason.

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='app.js'></script>
```

So how to add those 2 kind of script to my app?
I  tried different things in the manifest file but none of them have been successfull

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to avoid security issues is to download `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` and place it in your script directory. This will ensure you won't have security SOAP issues. Then include the files like this:

```
<script src='/example_local_directory/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='/example_local_directory/app.js'></script>
```

Comment: Much worse! The point being that you can't reference resources outside the app package; `..` can give a wrong idea, and `~` _will_ give a wrong idea.

Comment: And if I have google maps api link? how do I do this?